# git + bitbucket - ssh script issues

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, bitbucket

Bitbucket guide on using ssh provides a script, which I have added to the bashrc, but when it runs it just automatically says connected instead of requesting the passphrase. When I run

```
ssh-add -l
```

I get the message **"The agent has no identities."**

I am on windows, I have my .ssh directory set up, it has the config, environment, and known_host files. In addition, I have placed a KEYS directory here which holds the generated ssh keys.

The environment and known_host were generated but I created the config myself, 
it merely holds the following

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/KEYS/theMachine
```

I do not know what the environment files data means, so I won't post it for the moment.

The guide I am following is located here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

I have completed up to step 6 but I am stuck on step 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stored the key in different place and therefore the `ssh-add` can't find it (it does not read your config -- the tutorial is not so good).

You should move your `~/.ssh/KEYS/theMachine` to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Yes. And move also the `~/.ssh/KEYS/theMachine.pub` to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. It will solve your problem.

---

Alternative solution would be to modify the line in `~/.bashrc` from

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add
```

to

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add ~/.ssh/KEYS/theMachine
```

Answer (score 0):

> The agent has no identities.

For more information read this [For Unix, what are ssh-agent and ssh-add, and how do I use them?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aeww).

---

Follow those steps to start and add your ssh keys & agent.

```
# start the ssh agent service
eval $(ssh-agent)

# your keys should now be automatically loaded from the ~/.ssh folder
# but just in case to verify that they were loaded:
ssh-add
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the other answer I received worked so I accepted that. But could you explain what this does for future reference?

Comment: The ssh agent sometimes stop working so the eval simply restart it. when its restarted it reading the keys from the default location unless you give it diffrent location

Comment: `ssh-agent` itself should not stop working unless something around is broken. If the agent would not be running, it would write `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.`. This is really not answering the question.

Comment: Once in a while i have to use the eval to star the service. usually on vm images.